# Automatic login with Salesforce

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, oauth

I would really appreciate if anybody could guide me to achieve this requirement.
A user has told me recently that in his company, the technology team has developed a desktop app whose main purpose is to connect with salesforce using a Button. This app is just allowed for certain users with specific roles and profiles. They want this users to be able to login in salesforce automatically using the passwords they use in the company network (I assume the same active directory credentials), avoiding the login step, just to have the automatic authentication with salesforce and start to work.

Thanks a lot for your ideas, opinions, related tools or processes I could implement.

Comment: What you are looking for is Single Sign On (SSO). The [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_about.htm&type=5) and [Tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/identity_login/identity_login_sso) should help you.

Comment: @AayushK , Hi! thanks for the reply. Do you consider that is enough just with SSO? I´m afraid about the automatic login thing.

Comment: Yes. You will need to contact the team within your company that manages the corporate logins. They should be able to share the details related to the "Identity Provider" with you (certificate, entity url, federation ids etc) and once you configure SSO using those details, you should see a button on the Salesforce login that that the users can click to directly login to Salesforce without entering their username and password.